# Line fades at end of line instead of beggining

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, wacom

I'm trying to draw strait lines with the brush tool while holding the `SHIFT` key and tapping two points on the screen. The problem I'm having is the fade is at the beginning of the line instead of at the end.

**Is there a way to reverse this application of brush pressure?**

*I'm using Wacom Intuos Draw, Photoshop CC, Windows 10*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change Opacity Jitter Control to Fade. Then you need to play with the Fade and Minimum Number. Personally I'd start with a 65 fade, 35 min.

That should work for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan,
That does work, but only when overriding the pressure pen properties- 
![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMEDFOzmU9QaUZVVUhKbEkyQkk/view?usp=sharing).
This way all the lines look exactly the same. I hoped there would be a way to still use the pen pressure to get a more hand drawn look...well I guess that's the best there is...